# How to reference PowerShell Module within ASP.NET Site

Tags: asp.net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Microsoft Online Services Migration Toolkit PowerShell Commands from within an ASP.NET website (using vb.NET).

I've started off using a guide on how to use PowerShell in ASP.NET - from here: http://devinfra-us.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-powershell-20-from-aspnet-part-1.html

I'm trying to work out how to implement the Online Services Migration Toolkit PowerShell cmdlets.

Here is a snippet from my code-behind:

```
Sub GetUsers()

    Dim iss As InitialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
    iss.ImportPSModule(New String() {"MSOnline"})
    Using myRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss)
        myRunSpace.Open()

        ' Execute the Get-CsTrustedApplication cmdlet.
        Using powershell As System.Management.Automation.PowerShell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create()

            powershell.Runspace = myRunSpace

            Dim connect As New Command("Get-MSOnlineUser -Enabled")
            Dim secureString As New System.Security.SecureString()
            Dim myPassword As String = "ThePassword"

            For Each c As Char In myPassword
                secureString.AppendChar(c)
            Next

            connect.Parameters.Add("Credential", New PSCredential("admin@thedomain.apac.microsoftonline.com", secureString))
            powershell.Commands.AddCommand(connect)

            Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = Nothing
            Dim errors As Collection(Of ErrorRecord) = Nothing

            results = powershell.Invoke()
            errors = powershell.Streams.[Error].ReadAll()

            For Each obj As PSObject In results
                Response.Write(obj.Properties("Identity").Value.ToString())
            Next

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

When I try to run the code via the page, I'm getting the following error

> The term 'Get-MSOnlineUser -Enabled' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

So I'm guessing I haven't worked out how to import the Online Services Migration Toolkit PowerShell CmdLets. I'm also not exactly sure if the line:

```
iss.ImportPSModule(New String() {"MSOnline"})
```

Is exactly correct. Is there a way I can verify the Module name?

I'm also unsure of where and how to reference the .dll files. At the moment I have copied them to my bin folder but I can't add them as references, so how does the ImportPSModule statement know where to find them? Especially when the website is published to the final production server.

One other question, should I be using the x86 or x64 cmdlets? I'm developing on Win7 x64, but not sure if the website builds as x86 or x64? Do I need to find out what architecture the server is?

Answer (score 1):

"Get-MSOnlineUser -Enabled" is not a command; "Get-MSOnlineUser" is. I'm a bit confused how you got it correct further down the script with `connect.Parameters.Add("Credential", ...)` but didn't do the same thing for -Enabled.

Use `connect.AddArgument("Enabled")` or `connect.Parameters.Add("Enabled", true)` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried that... now the error reads: The term 'Get-MSOnlineUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I need to figure out how to make sure the ASP.NET site is accessing the cmdlets and make sure they're properly imported.

Comment: This is a completely stupid question, but did you actually install the MSOnline module on the ASP.NET server where you're trying to load it?